# Print out to file using Regex or Grep

Tags: python

I'm trying to check reverse lookup of IP address and then write the result to txt file. 
How I can write the result to file using regex or grep ?

My script:

```
import sys, os, re, shlex, urllib, subprocess 

cmd = 'dig -x %s @192.1.1.1' % sys.argv[1]

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

sys.stdout = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")
print(out)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: Use `open("/tmp/test.txt", "a")` instead of `open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")`

Comment: @ettanany You'd use 'r' here.